# Angular Material tabs adding custom icon/image before tab title

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have some tabs using Angular Material. I am trying to put in an image/icon before the title, But can't seem to see how to do it? I am using version 7 for Angular. My code so far is:

**html.file**

```
<div class="tabs">
    <nav mat-tab-nav-bar mat-align-tabs="left">
        <a mat-tab-link
           *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
           [routerLink]="link.path"
           routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
           [active]="rla.isActive">
          {{link.label}}
        </a>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

**ts.file**

```
export class ContentAreaComponent implements OnInit {

  navLinks = [
    {path: 'details', label: 'V Details'},
    {path: 'select', label: 'Product'},
    {path: 'clselect', label: 'Client Details'},
  ];
}
```

Comment: [Using tabs with a custom label template](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples), right in the tabs examples ...

Comment: Yes I have seen that, but the code structure is different above, as the titles are defined in the `.ts` file.

Comment: This is **exactly the same thing**, you just have to add a new tag to edit the tab title.

Comment: Could you show me an example, I'm fairly new to Angular

Comment: You have the example [right  in front of you](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples) !!!

Comment: Apologies but I can't see where to put the tag your referring to...

Comment: I'm done. Good luck with your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is follow [this](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples) example with the icons in the tabs. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-cx83pe?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) is a stackblitz from your code that shows icons in the tabs.

Change your template to:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <nav mat-tab-nav-bar mat-align-tabs="left">
        <a mat-tab-link
           *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
           [routerLink]="link.path"
           routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
           [active]="rla.isActive">
          <mat-icon class="example-tab-icon">{{link.icon}}</mat-icon>
          {{link.label}}
        </a>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

In your component add an icon property (see list of icons [here](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline)):

```
navLinks = [
    {path: 'details', label: 'V Details', icon: 'star'},
    {path: 'select', label: 'Product', icon: 'star_border'},
    {path: 'clselect', label: 'Client Details', icon: 'star_half'},
  ];
```

And maybe add some CSS to separate the icon from the tab label:

```
.example-tab-icon {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have been clearer, I need the icons to be different for each tab title.

Comment: Then add an additional property on you links with the icon name and use it for the mat-icon.

Comment: Post/Stackblitz is updated with an icon property so you can set the icon for each link via the property `icon`.

Comment: Thanks Fabian Küng, if I wanted the icon to be a image from my assets, would I just link the image inside of the icon: tag... like `{icon: 'assets/image.svg'},`

Comment: Most likely you will have to use an `img` tag to display your svg or image if it is an external asset.